# Is there some gulp plugin to remove empty class attr and whitespace around quote and doubel space inside class on html files?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp

Like this.

```
<button class="" disabled></button> // remove empty class and keep other attr like disabled
<div class=" a b "></div> // remove whitespace around quote
<div class="a  b"></div> // remove double space inside class
```

This is the result I want, i need to format html file but not minify.

```
<button disabled></button> // remove empty class and keep other attr like disabled
<div class="a b"></div> // remove whitespace around quote
<div class="a b"></div> // remove double space inside class
```

I tried some html format plugins but failed, hope you can recommend some plugins to me, thank you.

Comment: Since `gulp-replace` can use regex's you should be able to remove those.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations on external resources like plug-ins or libraries are off-topic for StackOverflow.